# how_remove_noise

Tags: arrays, plot, noise-reduction

I would like to know how noise can be removed from data (say, radio data that is an array of rows and columns with each data point representing intensity of the radiation in the given frequency and time).The array can contain radio bursts. But many fixed frequency radio noise also exists(RFI=radio frequency intereference).How to remove such noise and bring out only the burst.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude, but this question isn't clear at all. Please sharpen it up.

The normal way to remove noise is first to define it exactly and then filter it out.  Usually this is done in the frequency domain.  For example, if you know the normalized power spectrum `P(f)` of the noise, build a filter with response

```
e/(e + P(f))
```

where `e<1` is an attenuation factor.

You can implement the filter digitally using FFT or a convolution kernel.

When you don't know the spectrum of the noise or when it's white, then just use the inverse of the signal band.

Comment: Thanks Gene. I would like to send the actual data but don't know how to do that in the 'Ask question' forum in this site.

Comment: I will try to sharpen the question. The data is an array of 200 rows and 3600 columns. When plotted with pcolor();shading interp in matlab, it displays the feature (radio burst) along with fixed frequency radio noise. The data is the observation of Sun in a range of radio frequencies. The resulting picture is the dynamic spectrum that displays solar radio type II / type III bursts or other type bursts. The problem is to obtain a plot which shows only the bursts. This requires subtracting the other interference such as RFI (radio frequency interference).

Comment: This is still confusing.  Are you saying you have 200 spectral bands and 3,600 samples in each band?  What does a "burst" consist of in the data?  What is "fixed frequency radio noise?"  If it's really fixed frequency, then it will look like a constant value in each spectral band, and you simply subtract these out. But you must mean something more complicated than that...

Comment: Again thanks dear Gene. You are right that there are 200 spectral bands or frequencies from 45 MHZ. 3600 samples are observations of intensities over time in all frequencies. The burst is a solar radio type II burst that drift from higher frequencies to lower, as the shock moves from lower to higher corona in the sun. In some frequencies there is noise due to FM. We have remove this noise.Unfortunately I am yet to earn sufficient badges to post the actual data and the image. Can I have your email id.

Comment: The data and the picutre can be accessed in the following link.  http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=Data.mat&term=Data.mat

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish? A simple thresholding operation in bands 101 to 130 or so will isolate the duration of this burst (with the other bands merely ignored).